# Persistent connections with pipelining

Tags: browser, tcp

I have a question about the behavior of a browser( especially Firefox ) tackling with persistent connections:

Must all the requests sent in one pipelined persistent connection direct to the same server? What about a request specified by user from address bar -- may it reuse an already established persistent connection to send its request or need another connection?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Must all the requests sent in one pipelined persistent connection direct
> ```
>
> to the same server?

Yes, HTTP goes over TCP, and TCP is a connection between 2 hosts only.

> may it reuse an already established
>   persistent connection to send its
>   request or need another connection?

It may. I've not seen any browsers do that.